# Get the GazeProvider.GazeTarget when GaxePointer is always on

Tags: hololens, mrtk

In our app we have the gaze pointer behaviour set to be AlwaysOn:

`PointerUtils.SetGazePointerBehavior(PointerBehavior.AlwaysOn);`

This seems to break the GazeProvider because when a hand is detected, this:

```
CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeTarget
```

returns the object actually hit by the hand rays, instead of the object at which we are gazing (could be null).

This is the code I use to get the position of the hit:

```
    if (CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeTarget?.layer == 31)
    {
        Debug.Log(CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.HitInfo.point);
    }
```

But it returns the position of the hand cursor and not the gaze

I also tried filtering by SourceType(Head) but the problem persists:

```
    foreach (var source in CoreServices.InputSystem.DetectedInputSources)
    {
        if (source.SourceType == InputSourceType.Head && CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeTarget?.layer == 31)
        {
            foreach (var p in source.Pointers)
            {
                if (p is IMixedRealityPointer)
                {
                    Debug.Log("HIT");
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

So here is the question:
When the GazePointer is set to be always visible, how can we get the position of the gaze hit even if a hand is detected?

Answer (score 0):

To get the raw data of eye gaze and hand gaze at the same time, you can use [InputRayUtils class](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.InputRayUtils.html?q=InputRayUtils),  which provides the TryGetRay method that can get the ray associated with the desired input source type and hand. And if you have any question about how to use it, you can find an example in the InputDataExample scene under Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/Input/Scenes/InputData.

Comment: From what I see this will not give me access to the hit point of the gaze ray, just the direction and origin. I need to know the hit point in order to place an object but the gazeprovider returns the hit point of the hand ray and not the gaze.

Comment: You can use Physics.Raycast method to calculate the impact point in world space where the ray hit the collider based on the Ray instance assigned by TryGetRay. Try to add the following code to L48 of the [InputDataExample Class]( https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/5dc2cebcaed9a90d8019cda3d4933df03beb0bcd/Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/Input/Scenes/InputData/InputDataExample.cs) to see the behavior:
                    RaycastHit hitInfo;
                    UnityEngine.Physics.Raycast(myRay, out hitInfo);
                    sb.Append($" point: {hitInfo. point}");